# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No date'

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No date' in
>   Z:\home\formm.ru\www\handler.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   Z:\home\formm.ru\www\handler.php on line 4

Использую denwer, все настроено, база данных есть, таблица есть: 
БД - formm, таблица `bot_api`. Формат `Compact`, Сама структура таблицы:

```
bot_id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
bot_key text utf8_general_ci
bot_title varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
```

Запрос MYSQL (phpmyadmin):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `bot_api` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Форма index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Форма</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>name</h1>

    <form method="post" action="handler.php">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Сам Handler.php:

```
<?php

        if (!isset($POST['username'])) {
            throw new Exception('No date');
        }

        $yourValue = $POST['username'];
        //$connectString, $user и $pass - коннекты к бд
        $db = new PDO('localhost', 'root', '');
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bot_api (bot_key) VALUES (:bot_key)");
        $query->bindParam(':bot_key', $yourValue);
        $query->execute();

        $selectQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT bot_key FROM bot_api");
        $selectQuery->execute();
        $result = $selectQuery->fetchColumn();
        echo implode(' ', $result);


?>
```

Ругается на исключение, данные я передал в `username` в чем проблема я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `$POST` - не существует, нужно использовать `$_POST`, а вообще рекомендую, `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'название ключа');`

Comment: Спасибо. Но теперь начало ругаться на PDO: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name

Comment: Читайте документацию - первый параметр в конструкторе PDO - это и есть ваш data source name (http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо! теперь то у меня все работает безошибочно.